# Fseminf function with 2 dimensional x

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a little problem, fseminf used to work just fine, but now as I reached to it, it happend to produce an error, I have no idea what happend. Here is the code with an example which does not work:

```
clc;
clear;
close;

% Zdefiniuj funkcje
global g f S

f = @(x) (x(1)-2).^2 + (x(2)-0.2).^2;
g = @(x,s) 5.*x(1).^2.*sin(pi.*sqrt(s))./(1+s.^2) - x(2);
lb = [-1,0];
ub = [1 ,0.2];
S = [0,1];    
A = [];
b = [];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];
x0 = [0,0]';

[x,fval,exitflag,output,lambda] = fseminf(f,x0,1,@seminfcon2,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub);

disp('x=   ')
x
```

And seminfcon is defined:

```
function [c, ceq, K1, s] = seminfcon2(x,s)
global S g

% Dodatkowe parametry
c = [];
ceq = [];
if isnan(s(1,1))
            s(1,1)=0.001;
            s(1,2)=0;
end
t = S(1):s(1):S(2);
K1 = g(x,t);
```

The error is when calculating x, meaning in fseminf

Comment: What is the error message?!

Comment: It worked for me: 

Local minimum found that satisfies the constraints.

Optimization completed because the objective function is non-decreasing in 
feasible directions, to within the default value of the optimality tolerance,
and constraints are satisfied to within the default value of the constraint tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>

x =
    0.2052
    0.2000

Comment: Error in fseminf (line 69)
[x,fval,exitflag,output,lambda] = fseminf(f,x0,1,@seminfcon2,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub); anyway, it used to work on my computer too